# Problem with numeric variable in i.topo.corr

Tags: landsat, grass-7.0, grass.script, bash

I have a script to do topographic correction on [landsat](/questions/tagged/landsat) images.

Following the manual, I first have to create the illumination model. I do it with the following line:

```
i.topo.corr -i --overwrite output=temp basemap=DTM zenith=$zenith azimuth=$azim
```

When I launch it through the script the output is:

```
ERROR: Sorry <127.95340672> is not a valid option
ERROR: Missing value for parameter <azimuth>
```

What makes me crazy is that if I launch it interactively with the same numbers it works!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution:
apparently the bash script read the variable `$azim` as a string and not as a number (I didn't know this could happen in bash). The workaround to avoid the problem is perform  a mathematic operation with it so that it gets read as a number before  passing it to `i.topo.corr`:

```
az=$(echo $azim + 0 | bc)
```